# Тип сущности не входит в модель для текущего контекста

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework, orm

Продолжаю мучать Entity. Подход DataBaseFirst. Нужно добавить в таблицу запись (уникального первичного ключа в таблице нет). 
Контекст :

```
public partial class Entities : DbContext
{
    public Entities()
        : base("name=Entities")
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException();
    }

    public virtual DbSet<cashaccounts> cashaccounts { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<paper> paper { get; set; }
}
```

Сущность таблицы :

```
public partial class cashaccounts
{
    public string orderKlient { get; set; }
    public decimal CA_USD { get; set; }
    public decimal CA_EUR { get; set; }
    public decimal CA_GBP { get; set; }
    public decimal CA_SGD { get; set; }
    public decimal CA_AUD { get; set; }
    public decimal CashAllocation { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime DATEH { get; set; }
}
```

И метод добавляющий строку в таблицу :

```
    public void NewCashHistory(string order, decimal ca_usd, decimal ca_eur, decimal ca_gbp, decimal ca_sgd, decimal ca_aud, decimal cashallocation)
    {
        EF.HistoryDB.Entities HistoryDBContext= new EF.HistoryDB.Entities();
        var cashWritter = HistoryDBContext.cashaccounts;

        cashWritter.Add(new EF.HistoryDB.cashaccounts()
        {
            orderKlient = order,
            CashAllocation = Math.Round(cashallocation, 4),
            CA_USD = Math.Round(ca_usd, 4),
            CA_EUR = Math.Round(ca_eur, 4),
            CA_GBP = Math.Round(ca_gbp, 4),
            CA_AUD = Math.Round(ca_aud, 4),
            CA_SGD = Math.Round(ca_sgd, 4),
            DATEH = DateTime.Now
        });
        HistoryDBContext.SaveChanges();
    }
```

Модель :

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При вызове метода падает ошибка :

> Необработанное исключение типа "System.InvalidOperationException" в EntityFramework.dll
>   Дополнительные сведения: Тип сущности cashaccounts не входит в модель для текущего контекста.

В чем тут ошибка ?

Comment: А модель-то где?

Comment: @PavelMayorov извиняюсь, не понял. речь о edmx ?

Comment: о нем, конечно же. В текущем виде ваш пример не является полным. Кстати, еще было бы неплохо временно убрать таблицу paper и сократить число полей, чтобы он стал еще и минимальным.

Comment: @PavelMayorov там всего одна таблица, поэтому не включил сразу модель. Добавил.

Comment: Так, погодите. А куда тогда paper делась?

Comment: @PavelMayorov так `paper` не связана с cashaccount .

Comment: Но в модели-то она есть?

Comment: @PavelMayorov есть конечно, просто не думаю что с этой таблицей связана ошибка.

Comment: Странный у вас `OnModelCreating()`. Говорите, что у вас DataBaseFirst, ну так после команды `Scaffold-DbContext` в этом методе не может быть пусто или как у вас выбрасываться исключение.

Comment: @Bulson минуту, о каком Scaffold речь ?

Comment: Речь идет об [этом.](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/get-started/full-dotnet/existing-db)

Comment: @Bulson а, спасибо уже исправил - пересоздал edmx и эта проблема ушла.(видимо что то поменял в БД а edmx остался без изменений). С этой проблемой справился правда возникла другая -> о ней в другом вопросе.

Comment: А, так вы работаете со старым EF, а не с EFCore. Тогда моя ссылка вам не подходит.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема была в том, что если edmx создается DBfirst то после создания edmx модели в VS менять БД уже нельзя. Как решение - пересоздать edmx с теме же настройками уже по новой версии БД.